# Strange Structure of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, traversal

well I receive this kind of JSON data from an external server

```
{'mydata':[{'id':1012, 'username':'foo', 'password':'bar'}]}
```

now my problem is i can't traverse the `id` now how i can traverse it?. I think the extra `[]` makes the problem as i check it with this. http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/ceL2C/

now is there any possibility that i can still traverse the data in this kind of JSON structure?

Comment: This is valid json when dealing with a collection of objects. the [] indicates its an array. you can use a loop to iterate through each index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data is in an array, you simply need to refer to it as you would data in an array:

```
alert(window.data.mydata[0].id);
```

Alter your code to that, and it will work fine.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ceL2C/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `​window.data.mydata.map( function(i){return i.id} )​` to get the all the ids.